# Why is the filename incomplete when downloading from Google AppEngine Blobstore in Firefox?

Tags: google-app-engine, firefox, blobstore

I have a page on my GWT & App Engine application that is basically a table of files that the user has uploaded.

Here is the last part of the doGet function of BlobServiceImpl, that serves the blobs when the user requests:

```
    // got the entity already

    filename = (String) entity.getProperty("filename");

    resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + filename);

    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
```

The code above gets the filename from the entity metadata, set the filename in the HttpServletResponse and then serve the actual blob.

The problem I am having is that for files with a space in the filename, Firefox sets the filename to the first word only - everything after the space is excluded. This is quite annoying as a file called "My Amazing File.xls" will be saved as "My".

Something to do with the character encoding perhaps? Strange that it works fine in other browsers.

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amy has said, this is a Firefox problem, nothing to do with App Engine.

Changing this:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + filename);
```

To this:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

fixed my problem.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use a urlencode function on the filenames so that the " " become "%20".

Comment: I tried a String.replace(" ", "%20") on it already. The %20's get changed back into spaces in chrome but in firefox the filename is set with %20 instead of each space!

Comment: Also just tried URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8") but that replaces the spaces with "+" symbols :/

Comment: This looks like a well-known FF issue (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+download+spaces+in+filename). Apparently surrounding the filename parameter with double quotes will fix it (e.g. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/724438) -- give that a try.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot! Don't know why but I assumed it was a FF+GAE problem, not just a general FF problem. Thanks a ton for the help, Amy.